# Help for complicated table

Tags: tables

[image]

Dear all, I badly need a help with this table. This is my first table in LaTeX and I sat about one day to manage it but now at the point I cant cope with it in a short time. Here's what i tried to do

```
\begin{table}
  \centering\tlstyle
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{ |l|cc|cc|cc|cc|r| }
\hline
Metal&\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Voltage, experiment   (V)} & Voltage, calculated (V)\\ \hline
Cu & 0.64-0.68 & (1,5,f) & 0.44 & (1,6,f) & 0.8 & (2,4,b) & 0.8 & (1,4,7,d) & 0.81\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \item\label{tnote:bridge-1}That is, $360^\circ$ vision, as proposed by Noddy Norris.
      \item\label{tnote:bridge-2}As recommended by \emph{Robot Review}.
      \item\label{tnote:bridge-3}That is, X-Ray vision, as proposed by \emph{Mechanical Maniacs}.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
  \caption{\label{tab:bridge}Total values of Jim's technological options for robot projects he thinks possible.}
\end{table}
\begin{tabular}{ |l|l|l| }
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! If you show us what you managed to put together in this one day you worked on it, I'm sure we will be able to complete it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! We are not a do-it-for-me-service. If it's that urgent you can also try to make it in Word/LibreOffice/OpenOffice and use an online converter or try an online LaTeX table editor.

Comment: Your question is not appropriate for this site. My suggestion is, if you are under a deadline, to produce a PDF of the table you took a pic of in the question, and inline it in your latex using `\includegraphic`. Then, after the deadline frenzy, come back and search previous questions about tables

Comment: None of ur suggestios work. I tried to use word to latex converter but it made it worse than original. \includegraphic is not a solution i would merely convert my word to pdf which won't be accepted by journal. After digging a net all day long I started understand concept. I tried to build a table from the scratch but it became an issue for me thus I tried to find similar tables anyways couldn't adopt em for my table.

Comment: how can i put here my code or why can't i put it via "Add Comment"

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Make edit your question in order to add code (there's a button at the bottom left of the question on the other side to your username)

Comment: Thanx @Dai Bowen but why it looks so bad. Gotta beg an excuse for these questions. This is the second time i'm seeking help from this site. The first attempt was very fruitful

Comment: Please edit your question and make the code you posted compilable. It should be a complete minimal document, starting with `\documentclass`.

Comment: It's a paper. U want me to post the whole code?

Comment: Any to help? Plzzz

Comment: Referring to @cfr's comment. People here expect a code example that one can copy from your question and paste into a LaTeX editor and then can compile it. No further manual modifications should be needed. So copy the code that you provide and try to compile it without any further modification (in a new document). If that's not working then the code is not compilable.

Comment: If you are in such a hurry, then I would recommend that you generate the table using **Microsoft Excel** or any similar software. Export it as a **PDF** or any other appropriate format (**PNG** for example) and then include it with `\includegraphics` and so on.

Comment: It's a PAPER! And a journal won't accept it as i mentioned before.

Comment: I uploaded the code. And it's just a duplicate of another table similar to mine. I'm playing around jumping from one site to another to edit and correct this code to suit my table. And I'm still unlucky

Comment: I do understand tthat this site is not do-it-for me site and I was n't expecting it. I need just a code for a few rows, caption and footnote. If I get the point I'll proceed by myself I wasn't asking for the whole code. Thnx anyway

Comment: We don't want your whole document, no. But nobody can compile your code as is. They have to add a class and then figure out which packages you might be using. A lot of the commands in your code are not part of standard LaTeX. Without their definitions (or the packages which define them) nobody can reproduce the problem.

Comment: The table you say you wish to replicate is poorly, even shoddily designed. Why on earth would anyone want to replicate such a dreadful table? Do you expect to get help on how to create a dreadful-looking table? It would be so much easier to create a good-looking table from scratch...

Answer (score 2):

Not the best looking table, but changing `\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Voltage, experiment (V)}` to `\multicolumn{8}{|c|}{Voltage, experiment (V)}` solved most of the problems in your code.

Furthermore, to get linebreaks in `Voltage, calculated (V)`, you could use a column of fixed with.

---

If you have some time, please have a look at https://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/markusp/teaching/guides/guide-tables.pdf

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \caption{\label{tab:bridge}Total values of Jim's technological options for robot projects he thinks possible.}
  \centering
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{ |l|cc|cc|cc|cc|p{1.6cm}| }
            \hline
            Metal&\multicolumn{8}{|c|}{Voltage, experiment (V)} & Voltage, calculated (V)\\ \hline
            Cu & 0.64-0.68 & (1,5,f) & 0.44 & (1,6,f) & 0.8 & (2,4,b) & 0.8 & (1,4,7,d) & 0.81\\ 
            & 1.0-1.5 & (1,4,8,d) & 1.0-1.5 & (1,4,f) &&&&&\\
            \hline
            Cu & 0.64-0.68 & (1,5,f) & 0.44 & (1,6,f) & 0.8 & (2,4,b) & 0.8 & (1,4,7,d) & 0.81\\ 
            & 1.0-1.5 & (1,4,8,d) & 1.0-1.5 & (1,4,f) &&&&&\\           
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \item[1] That is, $360^\circ$ vision, as proposed by Noddy Norris.
      \item[2] As recommended by \emph{Robot Review}.
      \item[3] That is, X-Ray vision, as proposed by \emph{Mechanical Maniacs}.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My heartfull thnx.

Comment: @Make You're welcome! Can you please undo your last edit to your question? if you suddenly start talking about goalkeepers nobody will ever be able to understand it.

Comment: :)) OK. Thnk u for the link

Comment: Unf. I cant do it, I deleted it from original source and it was a good mess and compilation of what i learnt from my today's painful latex journey

Comment: Back to the question...

Comment: when i compile the doc the pdf prints kinda long dashed lines can u look through it? I mean vertical and horizontal lines r not connected...I tried to play with preamble didnt help

Comment: @Make As you can see from my screenshot, I get connected lines. If you get another result, please make a questions with a MWE that demonstrates the problem. We cannot read minds!

Comment: Hello world!The table i got coded by @samcarter and i dont understand why the lines r not connected and why cant i just upload it becase i have i dont have sufficient rank or smthng like that

Comment: @Make You should always have enough reputation to edit YOUR own questions.